# Trying to pass in an enum from another class

Tags: c++, class, enums

I have two classes one the Driver and the other one called FilterOut.  In Driver, I have an enum called lights that I passed in correctly into FilterOut as an int.  I am having trouble figuring out how to do this as a enum.

The enum in my Driver class

```
enum lights{yellow, green, red, blue};
```

This worked for me.

```
void FilterOut::LightIn(int light)
  {
       switch(light);
  }
```

What I would like to do.

```
void FilterOut::LightIn(lights light)
  {
       switch(light);
  }
```

I tried this and several variations but have had no luck, any ideas? I have also tried to include an enum in FilterOut that is the same as the one in Driver and that has now worked either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the enum is in the `Driver` class, then you have to qualify its name:

```
class FilterOut {
 public:
  void LightIn(Driver::lights light);
};

void FilterOut::LightIn(Driver::lights light)
{
   switch(light);
}
```

You also have to qualify the look-up scope when calling the function:

```
FilterOut f;
f.LightIn(Driver::red);
```

Comment: Make sure the enum is in a public section as well.

Comment: And when he invokes `FilterOut::LightIn()`, he'll need to qualify the enumerated constant, also: `int main () { ...; fo.LightIn(Driver::yellow); ... }`

Comment: @Robᵩ Thanks, added an example.